# CSS background image using gradients in IE

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, background, textures

How can I use/convert this brick pattern to appear correctly in Internet Explorer?

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mstiller/LcLpr8a3/8/

```
.bricks {
background-color: #fff8dc;
background-size: 58px 58px;
background-position: 0px 2px, 4px 35px, 29px 31px, 34px 6px;
background-image: linear-gradient(335deg, #942626 23px, transparent 23px) 0 2px, linear-gradient(155deg, #b22222 23px, transparent 23px) 4px 35px, linear-gradient(335deg, #942626 23px, transparent 23px) 29px 31px, linear-gradient(155deg, #b22222 23px, transparent 23px) 34px 6px;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(115deg, #942626 23px, transparent 23px), -webkit-linear-gradient(295deg, #b22222 23px, transparent 23px), -webkit-linear-gradient(115deg, #942626 23px, transparent 23px), -webkit-linear-gradient(295deg, #b22222 23px, transparent 23px);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(115deg, #942626 23px, transparent 23px), -ms-linear-gradient(295deg, #b22222 23px, transparent 23px), -ms-linear-gradient(115deg, #942626 23px, transparent 23px), -ms-linear-gradient(295deg, #b22222 23px, transparent 23px);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(115deg, #942626 23px, transparent 23px), -moz-linear-gradient(295deg, #b22222 23px, transparent 23px), -moz-linear-gradient(115deg, #942626 23px, transparent 23px), -moz-linear-gradient(295deg, #b22222 23px, transparent 23px);
-pie-background: linear-gradient(335deg, #942626 23px, transparent 23px) 0 2px / 58px, linear-gradient(155deg, #b22222 23px, transparent 23px) 4px 35px / 58px, linear-gradient(335deg, #942626 23px, transparent 23px) 29px 31px / 58px, linear-gradient(155deg, #b22222 23px, transparent 23px) 34px 6px / 58px, #fff8dc;
 behavior: url("../pie/PIE.htc");
```

Comment: Does including it as a repeating background image work? i.e. have a file bg.png for ie browsers.

Comment: Why yes it would :-). I will probably resort to that, but I was hoping for a 'code' solution, for the sake of knowlege.